# How to set timeout for Orchestration in Azure Durable function

Tags: c#, .net, azure

```
[Function("TimerTrigger_EveryMinute")]
public async Task TimerTrigger_EveryMinute(
[TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")] TimerInfo timerInfo,
[DurableClient] DurableTaskClient starter)
{
    _logger.LogError($"Running timer trigger");

    string instanceId = await starter.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync("ORCHESTRATOR_TRIGGER_NAME");
    await starter.WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync(instanceId);

    _logger.LogInformation($"Completed orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'");
}


 [Function("ORCHESTRATOR_TRIGGER_NAME")]
 public async Task Run(
     [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
 {
    //long running function

     await Task.WhenAll(response);
 }
```

**what i need:-

1)after calling Orchestration i need timeout at 30sec,so after timeout it should end/exit.
or
2)is there any way we can do timeout for this WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync().**

Answer (score 0):

After calling the Orchestration function, you can set the timeout to 30 seconds in the following way-

```
[Function("ORCHESTRATOR_TRIGGER_NAME")]
public static async Task<bool> Run(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
{
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    DateTime deadline = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(timeout);

    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        Task activityTask = context.CallActivityAsync(your activity function);
        Task timeoutTask = context.CreateTimer(deadline, cts.Token);

        Task winner = await Task.WhenAny(activityTask, timeoutTask);
        if (winner == activityTask)
        {
            // success case
            cts.Cancel();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // timeout case
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You can refer to this [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers?tabs=csharp#usage-for-timeout) for more details.

You can also set the timeout at function level by adding `{ "functionTimeout": "00:00:30" }` in the `host.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.
What if there are more than one ActivityTrigger,will it work?. I provided more code below.

```
[Function("TimerTrigger_EveryMinute")]
public async Task TimerTrigger_EveryMinute(
[TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")] TimerInfo timerInfo,
[DurableClient] DurableTaskClient starter)
{
    _logger.LogError($"Running timer trigger");

    string instanceId = await starter.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync("ORCHESTRATOR_TRIGGER_NAME");
    await starter.WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync(instanceId);

    _logger.LogInformation($"Completed orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'");
}


 [Function("ORCHESTRATOR_TRIGGER_NAME")]
 public async Task Run(
     [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
 {
    var parallelTasks = new List<Task<int>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Task<int> task = context.CallActivityAsync<int>("getdata", i);
        parallelTasks.Add(task);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, It will work for this code as well.

Comment: Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-phone-verification?tabs=csharp