Azure Durable Functions - HttpClient Timeout WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync
I'm working on a durable function and would like to be able to cancel the function after a given time. Currently I have setup a timeout on both the start and completion of the instance. The weird thing is that I receive the following exception on the WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync method:

The WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync operation was canceled.

with inner exception:

The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.

and source:

Microsoft.DurableTask.Client.Grpc

This while I did set a higher timeout than 100sec.
Here Is the code that triggers the orchestration:
public class Trigger(IMessageMapper<StartOrganizationMessage> mapper)
{

    [Function(nameof(Trigger))]
    public async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("pipelinepriorityqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", IsSessionsEnabled = false)]
        ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
        ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions,
        [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient taskClient,
        FunctionContext context)
    {
        string? instanceId = null;
        try
        {
            var mappedMessage = mapper.ToApplicationMessage(message);

            instanceId = await taskClient.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync($"{nameof(OrganizationOrchestrator)}", Tuple.Create(mappedMessage.OrganizationId, mappedMessage.SecretId, mappedMessage.Farms));

            var waitForInstanceStart = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            var result = await taskClient.WaitForInstanceStartAsync(instanceId, waitForInstanceStart.Token);

            var waitForInstanceCompletion = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
            result = await taskClient.WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync(instanceId, true, waitForInstanceCompletion.Token);

            await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           await messageActions.DeadLetterMessageAsync(message, deadLetterErrorDescription: ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            await taskClient.PurgeInstanceAsync(instanceId!, new PurgeInstanceOptions { Recursive = true });
        }
    }
}


I tried setting the functionTimeout in the host.json but that did not seem to do the trick.
I would expect the timeout to occur after the cancelation token. Not after 100sec.
This is happening locally, not yet tried on test but would like to know the reason of this.
Edit 1:
Maybe also good to know is that in this case the activities that the orchestration started will keep running till they are finished.

It looks like you're wanting the Service Bus trigger function to wait for the Durable Orchestration to finish, but the Orchestration might take many minutes to complete (or even to timeout.) Setting aside the 100s Function timeout problem; is there a risk of Service Bus timeouts, due to your Function not completing the SB message within the timescale that SB expects? I don't think Functions and Service Bus triggers are designed to be long-lived. Maybe you need to re-think the architecture so the Orchestration is started but not awaited here?

Have you tried using context.CreateTimer as given in this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77265728/how-to-set-timeout-for-orchestration-in-azure-durable-function

Thanks to Andrews comment I indeed moved to a architecture where we don't await the orchestration.
